# dns problem; dig, nslookup work. ping, browser doesn't

Tags: dns

Here is what I have on an opensuse laptop:

```
$ping www.google.com
...Name or service not known

$nslookup www.google.com
Server: 80.80.80.80
...
..
Non-authorative answer:
Name: www.google.com
Address: 216.58.215.100
...
```

`$dig google.com` Also works fine

My `resolv.conf` has `nameserver 80.80.80.80` (as used by nslookup and dig)

My `nsswitch` has `hosts: files dns`

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: try nc google.com 80. once it connects, type GET / and see if you get any output

Comment: Used firefox and falkon.

Comment: $nc google.com 80. Get me a nc: getaddrinfo for host google.com port 80 Name or service not known

Comment: What does `grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf` show?  What are the file permissions on `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?  Does `sudo ping www.google.com` work?

Comment: Sudo ping www.google.com doesnt work. Nsswitch.com has -rw-r--r-- permissions. I have hosts: files dns

Comment: I can also access websites (in browsers) by using their ip...

Comment: Do `strace -e open ping www.google.com`.  Does it successfully open `libnss_dns`?  If it doesn't even try to open that library then there's probably a typo or some other problem in nsswitch.conf.

Comment: Nope it never even open nsswitch.conf.   comparing to strace ping on another computer, the laptop with the issue stops opening after opening many /usr/lib/locale/ and /usr/share/locale/ files. The last line before strace write the ping error message is trying to open libc.mo in some /usr/share/locale subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

So my current answer is to stop the nscd service. Seems many command (e.g. curl) checks there first but have workarounds. Ping will fail as it only checks with nscd. So far everything works.